# Change the value for a Json attribute

Tags: c#, json

I have the next JSON

```
{
   "attrib1":"value1",
   "attrib2":"value2",
   "attrib3":"value3"
}
```

this Json are saved into a `JObject`, and I want to create some function that change an specific value of this Json, in this case the `attrib1`, just like:

```
JObject ChangeJson(JObject request,string new_value)
{
  //some stuff to change the value from "attrib1"="value1" to "new_value"
}
```

the new Json:

```
    {
       "attrib1":"new_value",
       "attrib2":"value2",
       "attrib3":"value3"
    }
```

Hope you can help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse json in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-to-parse-json-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope this will help

`request.attrib1 = "new_value";`

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to tell me that you tried to find a answer yourself?

Rules:

> Don't ask about...
>
> Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)

Anyway...

```
request["attrib1"] = "new_value";
```

will do the Job.
It will modify the request object in-place.